# Python/Django Strange behavior with object dictionary and __dict__

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a portion of a Django project that involves submitting apartment applications into a system and I am noticing strange behavior with finding an application using the ORM and then turning the object into a dict calling `__dict__` in order to pre-populate a form.

I am curious if anybody can explain either what is happening or what I am doing wrong. Basically, I have a Foreign Key in my `UnitApplication` model so Applications are mapped to Properties, this database column name and the attribute name in my Model is `property_id`, however when I turn the object to a dictionary it appends an extra `_id` to the field name.

Here is my code:

```
application_id = request.GET.get('application_id')
application = UnitApplication.objects.using(db_alias).get(id=application_id)

# this is in a view so property_id == Property Object (1)
print(application.property_id)

# this will print my actual property_id, which is 1
print(application.property_id.id)

# this is the odd behavior, here is the dict that prints, and hinders form filling
# {..., 'property_id_id': 1, ...}

print(application.__dict__)
```

What is going on? I can fix this by editing the dict, but I feel like this is buggy.

Here are the relevant parts of my Model in the event you are curious about my naming:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    # I know this isn't needed but it makes me feel better seeing it here
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    rental_add_ons = models.ManyToManyField('RentalAddOns', related_name='rental_add_ons')

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    ...

class UnitApplication(models.Model):

    # property id, set to null if property removed from db
    property_id = models.ForeignKey('Property', 
                                    null=True, 
                                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    db_column='property_id')
```

**Note:** I am using a regular `Form` for this because it provided me a bit more freedom, I am not looking for suggestions on changing this around to use a `Model Form`, I have done that, and although this issue doesn't happen there, it was not ideal for my needs.

Comment: Can you show us your models.py for UnitApplication and Property? I suspect you appended an `_id` suffix to your model field, when django automatically does it for foreignkeys.

Comment: Nope I specifically named the column `property_id` inside the declaration of the attribute. Give me a sec, I'll post it

Comment: Really the answer is not to use `__dict__`. It's not meant for external use. If you need to serialize your model, use a serializer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay that lead to research, Django's `model_to_dict()` method out of `django.forms` does exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to share a way I figured out to turn an object to a dictionary using Django's built-in features. It has seemed from comments and answers here that I shouldn't use `__dict__`.

```
from django.forms import model_to_dict

application = UnitApplication.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('application_id'))

accurate_dictionary = model_to_dict(application)
print(accurate_dictionary)
```

Now this works:

```
form = UnitApplicationForm(initial=accurate_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to implement a method that returns the fields you want, in the format you want them. `__dict__` is not meant to be accessed directly, and there might be some internal operations that are causing the inconsistency you see.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you named your field `primary_id` in `UnitApplication`. Django automatically appends `_id` to any field that is a foreignkey, so you doing it makes it redundant. If you view your actual database, you can see that the column name will also be `property_id_id`.

To fix this, you can rename your `property_id` field to just `property`, and then remigrate.

Comment: False, look at my code... `db_column='property_id'` very clearly shows you what my database column name is. I posted my Model to discourage answers telling me my naming is wrong.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing that out. But perhaps the `__dict__` method still appends the `_id` suffix? If it is possible for you to test, it would be worth looking into, as I'm not sure how it is meant to behave.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach than `__dict__` might be using [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) which returns a queryset of dictionaries instead of model objects, or using [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms).

What Django does when you define a foreign key in a model is this: It saves the referred object's primary key in the database table in the column `<field_name>_id`.

Since you named your `ForeignKey` field `property_id`, Django created a `property_id_id` column in the database in which to save the foreign key. (It's obvious why convention calls for naming foreign key fields after the Model they refer to, without adding `_id`, in this case `property`.)

You can access this attribute on any `UnitApplication` object. The following would evaluate to true:

`unitapp.property_id_id == unitapp.property_id.id`

In both cases you are accessing the primary key of the related object, once from the main model, once from the related model.

When you call `__dict__` on a model object, foreign keys are represented as just ids, and their key is the colum name. You don't get a handle on the actual related object.